# Resize a UIView to allow space for ad unit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwindow, react-native

I am trying to add an ad unit above a subclass of UIView `RCTRootView`. This would move the `RCTRootView` down about 50px. This is my current attempt.

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                  moduleName:@"test"
                                               launchOptions:launchOptions];



CGRect frame = rootView.frame;
  frame.size.height -= 50;
  rootView.frame = frame;

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
```

This is a React Native project, so use of a StoryBoard. How can I resize the rootView?

How can I instantiate and append a viewController within UIWindow that is above the rootView (Ad unit)?

Comment: I would suggest use autolayout. It's far more simpler than this.

Comment: Suggestion on how to start adding StoryBoard to the project? mihir?

Comment: what is the result of you code ?

Comment: can you share the screen shot !

Comment: I could be missing something obvious, but if this is a React-Native project, why are you trying to do this in Obj-C? This seems like the type of thing RN and JSX would be super convenient for.

Comment: Why not just edit code in React Native instead of objective C?

Comment: In your example, you're setting `frame` but never using it. Instead you're using `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`. Try fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use container view controller to kind of compose 2 view controllers into one.

1. Create containerViewController:

   ```
   UIViewController* containerViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   ```
2. Create your child view controllers, that you will add to container view controller:

   > In your case they will be `rootViewController` and `adViewController`, in the example I'll call them `firstChildViewController` and `secondChildViewController`).

   ```
   UIViewController* firstChildViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   UIViewController* secondChildViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   ```
3. Add your child view controllers to container view controller in right order:

   > If `firstChildViewController` should be above `secondChildViewController`, then first add `secondChildViewController` and then `firstChildViewController` to create right subviews hierarchy).
   >
   > **Do not forget about layout your child view controller's views (TODO's are set where it is needed).**

   ```
   [containerViewController addChildViewController:firstChildViewController];
   [containerViewController.view addSubview:firstChildViewController.view];
   // TODO: layout firstChildViewController.view in containerViewController.view here
   [firstChildViewController didMoveToParentViewController:containerViewController];

   [containerViewController addChildViewController:secondChildViewController];
   [containerViewController.view addSubview:secondChildViewController.view];
   // TODO: layout secondChildViewController.view in containerViewController.view here
   [secondChildViewController didMoveToParentViewController:containerViewController];
   ```

   > To layout container view controller's views trust them as regular `UIView`'s and use preferred method to set their coordinates and sizes (autolayout or manual layout).
   >
   > To move view down 50px you should, for example, constraint bottom of the top view to top of the bottom view and height of the top view to 50.

There you go, you have two view controllers layed out as you need and all you need to do is to set `containerViewController` to `window`'s `rootViewController`:

```
[window setRootViewController:containerViewController];
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may helps, but probably solving this is React is better than changing screen size

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
rootViewController.view = rootView;
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
rootViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-50);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by mihir mehta storyboard is most convenient way to handle UI in iOS. Here is link from where you can learn to add story board. 
[Creating a new storyboard in XCode and making it the main one (black screen in simulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290404/creating-a-new-storyboard-in-xcode-and-making-it-the-main-one-black-screen-in-s)
Also there are ample tutorials on subject.