# Creating a new storyboard in Xcode and making it the main one (black screen in simulator)

Tags: ios, xcode

I accidentally deleted my original Main.storyboard file that came with the project when I first began it. Now, I need all of the steps necessary to create a new storyboard and make it the new main storyboard for the project. I only need one storyboard. When I run my app in simulator my whole app is just a black screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am programming in Swift.

Comment: and maybe one of the reason developers get black screen is  when they don't have an initial view controller.Make sure you'll have one of your view controller as initial view controller.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*You need to make the following things to get it to work:*

**1.** Create a new file

[image: Add file]

---

**2.** Select, name and save the Storyboard file

[image: Storyboard]

---

**3.** Select the file in the *Deployment Info*

[image: deployment info]

---

**4.** Drag a view controller into the file and select it as initial view controller (look at the inspector on the right)

[image: view controller]

Answer (score 6):

Let Me come up with a better solution

> **Method 1**

if you have deleted the story board as remove refrence like this

[image]

don't worry about anything your storyboard is still safe.

inside your project suppose you have your project saved on desktop as project1 go to project1 then you'll see a couple of folders find a folder named **project1**

Open it and you'll see some file's like this

[image]

all you have to do is go to Base.ipoj folder and if you find these files

[image]

either you can drag the file to your project or you can add them by this way.

[image]

browse your file For example desktop/project1/project1/Base.Iproj/Main.Storyboard

[image]

click on Add button and you'll have your Storyboard file.

and if you deleted the file by selecting "Move to trash" You can look up into trash copy your file to another folder and add the file as mentioned in the above steps.

> **Method 2**

if you want to add a new Storyboard just do :-

[image]

[image]

click on Next and save it and You'll have your new Storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Add new storyboard(New File..User Interface) ,then go to project's target ,then in (Main Interface) field add your storyboard name .

Answer (score 2):

I Also noticed that you have asked about assign the storyboard's view controller as the main one :-

here's the way :-

[image]

Click on View Controller

[image]

Open Attribute Inspector

[image]

Select View Controller as the initial one and you're ready to go.